# In python, how to share (the reference of) a variable as attributes across different objects?

Tags: python, class, reference, pass-by-reference

So I have a main class and several auxiliary classes. In the main class's methods, I'll need some auxiliary objects, with which I want to "share" the main instance's `shared_data` attribute, so that whenever I change the `shared_data` attribute of the main object, the auxiliary objects' corresponding attributes will update accordingly too. (For concreteness, you may think of the `shared_data` as "time", and I want the "time" attribute to stay synced across the various object).

However, it seems that doing this in the naive way as below will not work, because that would not actually "share" the data across objects, but rather just assign the current value to these objects, so these object attributes would not stay synced. What should be the correct way to implement this "syncing" or "sharing" functionality?

```py
class Main:

    def __init__(self, shared_data):
        self.shared_data = shared_data
        pass

    def do_stuff(self):
        # initialise auxiliary objects (only for once).
        # hopefully when self.x1 is changed, the data in
        # the objects aux1, aux2 will also reflect this change
        aux1, aux2 = Aux1(self.shared_data), Aux2(self.shared_data)

        # however, in general, changing self.shared_data would not
        # change the data in aux1 or aux2
        another_value = ...
        self.shared_data = another_value    # doesn't work

        pass


class Aux1:

    def __init__(self, x1):
        self.x1 = x1
        ...
        pass


class Aux2:

    def __init__(self, x2):
        self.x2 = x2
        ...
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is fine except this part:

```
self.shared_data = another_value    # doesn't work
```

That line does not modify the `shared_value`. It just assigns a different object to the variable which was before that holding the shared data object.

What you need to do instead is to modify `shared_value`, for example like this:

```
self.shared_value.data = another_data
```

---

Here is a complete example:

```
class SharedData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.time = 0
        self.colour = "red"


class ObjectWithSharedData:
    def __init__(self, shared_data):
        self._shared_data = shared_data

    def do_stuff(self):
        self._shared_data.time = 7

    def get_time(self):
        return self._shared_data.time


shared_data = SharedData()
a = ObjectWithSharedData(shared_data)
b = ObjectWithSharedData(shared_data)
c = ObjectWithSharedData(shared_data)

a.do_stuff()

print(a.get_time())  # prints 7
print(b.get_time())  # prints 7
print(c.get_time())  # prints 7
```

Comment: IIRC, for instance if the shared data is `time`, then maybe I want to create a `class Clock: def __init__(self, time): self.time = time`, and then modify `clock.time` instead of reassigning the `clock`? (Or rather, just sharing the `clock` instead of sharing `time`)

Comment: Yes, sharing a `clock` and modifying `clock.time` will work as well.

Comment: May I ask one follow up question: does Python just create a single one piece of `shared_data` in the memory, and sharing it across different objects simply create references to it, without additional memory usage? Let's now say the `shared_data` is large, will sharing it across many objects lead to significant memory overhead? Thanks!

Comment: Assigning `shared_data` to multiple variables just creates multiple references to the same data, so there's just a few bytes used for each of them. The data is not copied.